# Only update one property of the collection's field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Current application logic requires to store user records by years and will look something like:

```
balanceRecords: {
  2017: {
  ...,
    12: { ... }
  },
  2018: {
  ...,
    12: { ... }
  },
  2019: {
    ...,
    8: { ... }
  }
}
```

[image]

I've tried to update the document by ID inside the `users` collections

```
// year --> returned from the for loop operation from [2017, 2018, 2019]
firebaseDb.collection(`users`).doc(fyuAqykYpMVnB0h9grdznZgEcaU2)
            .update( personalData: {
               [year]: {}
            })
            .then(...)
            .catch(...)
```

Doing this I came to conclusion that each time I just overwrite the `balanceRecords` fields inside the document. Is it in general possible to update just a property of deep-nested field or it's expected that `sub-collections` are used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ``` doc(``) ``` doesn't help anything.  Just remove that.

You can use dot notation to update a deep property.  I changed some of your sample code because it had syntax errors and apparently was updating a different property than the one you highlighted.

```
firebaseDb.collection('users').doc('fyuAqykYpMVnB0h9grdznZgEcaU2')
    .update( `balanceRecords.${year}`: {
        // whatever properties you want
    })
```

Comment: Thank you @doug, that was actually easy :)

Comment: I've managed to make it work but with the following update payload: ```.update({ [`balanceRecords.${year}`]: {} })```